# SonarQube not able to read jacoco.exec file

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

We are using below versions to get JaCoCo Code Coverage report on SonarQube.

SonarQube 5.6.6
JaCoCo 0.7.9
Apache Ant 1.10.1
JUnit 4.12
JMockIt 1.20

We execute Jenkins job nightly to perform code analysis using SonarQube. We execute JUnit cases and gather code coverage of application.

We perform below steps as part of Sonar snapshot execution as part of Ant build.
1) Build the application
2) Execute JUnit Cases
3) Code Coverage
4) Sonar analysis

Now we frequently show failure in Jenkins sonar job due to SonarQube analysis failed and not able to application snapshot on Sonar server. If we execute Ant sonar target manually then we it was successful and snapshot generate without any problem in code coverage.

```
[sonar:sonar] Sensor SurefireSensor
[sonar:sonar] parsing D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\latest
[sonar:sonar] Resource not found: junit.framework.JUnit4TestCaseFacade
[sonar:sonar] Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=3343ms
[sonar:sonar] Sensor JaCoCoSensor
[sonar:sonar] Analysing D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\latest\jacoco.exec

BUILD FAILED
D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\build.xml:2246: 
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Unable to read 
D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\latest\jacoco.exec
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoReportReader.readJacocoReport(JacocoReportReader.java:78)
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:140)
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:114)
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoSensor.analyse(JaCoCoSensor.java:57)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java
Total time: 21 minutes 19 seconds
```

Following is the Ant "sonar" target configuration.

```
<target name="sonar" depends="init" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
<classpath>
<pathelement path="../../SONARlib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.jar" />
</classpath>
</taskdef>
<tstamp>
<format property="sonar_starttime" pattern="dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm" />
</tstamp>
<echo>Sonar Scan Start Time:${sonar_starttime}</echo>
<property name="sonar.projectBaseDir" 
value="<project_dir>" />
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="<sonar_server>" />
<property name="sonar.login" 
value="<sonar_token>" />
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="<project_key>" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="<project_name>" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="(R4_3)_${sonar_starttime}" />
<property name="sonar.analysis.mode" value="publish" />
<property name="sonar.language" value="java" />
<property name="sonar.java.source" value="1.8" />
<property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

<property name="sonar.sources" value="src/java,src/gradleSource" />
<property name="sonar.inclusions" value="**/*.java" />
<property name="sonar.tests" value="src/tests" />
<property name="sonar.test.inclusions" value="**/*Test.java" />
<property name="sonar.test.exclusions" 
value="**/*SuiteTest.java,**/*Expectation.java" />
<property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="${build.root}/${appname}/WEB-
INF/classes" />
<property name="sonar.java.test.binaries" 
value="${build.root}/${appname}/WEB-INF/classes" />
<property name="sonar.java.libraries" 
value="${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/*.jar,${build.root}/${appname}/WEB-
INF/lib/*.jar,${tomcat.root}/lib/*.jar,JUnitlib/*.jar,
ANTlib/*.jar,SVNlib/*.jar,JAXBlib/*.jar,../SONARlib/*.jar" />
<property name="sonar.java.test.libraries" 
value="${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/*.jar,${build.root}/${appname}/WEB-
INF/lib/*.jar,${tomcat.root}/lib/*.jar,JUnitlib/*.jar,
ANTlib/*.jar,SVNlib/*.jar,JAXBlib/*.jar,../SONARlib/*.jar" />
<property name="sonar.scm.disabled" value="false" />
<property name="sonar.scm.provider" value="svn" />
<property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="jacoco" />
<property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" 
value="${junit.xml.exec.latest.dir}/jacoco.exec" />
<property name="sonar.junit.reportsPath" 
value="${junit.xml.exec.latest.dir}" />
<sonar:sonar />
<tstamp>
<format property="sonar_endtime" pattern="dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm" />
</tstamp>
<echo>Sonar Scan End Time:${sonar_endtime}</echo>
```

Please let me know if you need further details.

Could you please help why this JaCoCo exception occur while sonar analysis?

Comment: What is the value of `${junit.xml.exec.latest.dir}`, and is it relative to the project/analysis directory or absolute? Hint: absolute is bad.

Comment: It is absolute path but it refers to project directory where we store jacoco.exec file. However, everytime jacoco analyis doesn't fail. We observed that 3/5 time it failes and we run sonar target manually and at that time it pass and able to generate code coverage properly.

Comment: Hint: absolute is bad.

Comment: Run Ant in verbose mode (`ant -v`) to get fuller stack trace containing `Caused by`. Also try to run JaCoCo Ant Task for generation of report (http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) - it might provide better error message. Usually this is caused by corrupted `class` and `exec` files, or by an attempt to analyse different class files with same class name.

Comment: Thank Godin. We already had ant task to generate coverage report. We run it and see that this error comes during coverage report generation or not. I believe this error comes when Sonar tries to get jacoco.exec file and some how due to corrution or any other issue it doesn't get coverage data and fails.

Comment: I enabled JaCoCo coverage report generation and it failed not able to generate coverage report.

Comment: Following is the exception.

Comment: [jacoco:report] Loading execution data file D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\latest\jacoco.exec

BUILD FAILED
D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\build.xml:2150: Unable to read execution data file D:\Projects\Collaborate\Branches\R4_3\deployment\latest\jacoco.exec

Comment: Do you got the exact solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of cases, jacoco.exec is just not uet generated.

So i suggest that you check the reasons of generation fail exp :

- Project build failed.
- Build not even triggered.